# In grafana , if I need to set a template can be used in all dashboards ,how can I do?

Tags: templates, grafana

In grafana ,  if I need to set a template can be used in all dashboards ,how can I do ?

Comment: As of now, There are no such option in grafana. Everything you create is specific to dashboard only.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to create individual templates for every dashboard that I have encountered. Both on Grafana 2.x and 3.0.4.

If you need the same template on every dashboard, I would create a blank dashboard, and configure that template. Then, reimport that json configuration file for all the dashboards. Just save it under a new name every time you import, so there are no duplicates.